# mySQL join question

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

The following line is giving an error message.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM products AS p LEFT JOIN categories AS c USING ON c.id = p.category_id WHERE c.name = "Galleri1"
 AND p.status = "active"' ;
 $Q = $this->db->query($query);
```

Data base structure.
CATEGORIES

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `shortdesc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `longdesc` text NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive') NOT NULL,
  `parentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
...
...
```

PRODUCT

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `shortdesc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `longdesc` text NOT NULL,
  `thumbnail` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `class` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `grouping` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','inactive') NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `featured` enum('true','false') NOT NULL,
  `price` float(4,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;
```

Error message

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON c.id = p.category_id WHERE c.name = "Galleri1" AND p.status = "active"' at line 1

SELECT * FROM products AS p LEFT JOIN categories AS c USING ON c.id = p.category_id WHERE c.name = "Galleri1" AND p.status = "active"
```

Q1. Could anyone point out my mistake plese?

Q2. Could anyone tell me how to write this in Codeigniter's Active Record class ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use single quotes, get rid of `USING` and make the `JOIN` inner:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    products AS p
JOIN    categories AS c
ON      c.id = p.category_id
WHERE   c.name = 'Galleri1'
        AND p.status = 'active'
```

- Double quotes are used to mark reserved words which you use as table and column names. The string literals should be enclosed into single quotes.
- `JOIN USING (col1)` means that you have a field named `col1` in both tables and want to join on it. If you don't, you should use `JOIN ON`
- Placing this condition `c.name = 'Galleri1'` into the `WHERE` clause makes the `LEFT JOIN` to return exactly same records as an `INNER JOIN` would. The latter is more efficient (since the optimizer can select which table to make leading in the join).

Comment: Thanks. It solve this problem. But I got another one. After this query, 
if ($Q->num_rows() > 0){
       foreach ($Q->result_array() as $row){
         $data = array(
          "id" => $row['id'],
  "name" => $row['name'],
          "shortdesc" => $row['shortdesc'],
  ...
  "category" => $row['categories.name']
I get an error for the last one. How assign categories' name?

Comment: `@shin`: you better post it as a another question.

Comment: Ok. I posted here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828406/how-to-get-data-from-a-joined-table

Answer (score 0):

`USING` and `ON` are two different ways to specific which columns to perform a join with. Your query is specifying both, but it looks like you are trying to use the `ON` syntax. Try the following:

`SELECT * FROM products AS p LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = p.category_id WHERE c.name = "Galleri1"`